# update max id_post only from table in job crons, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, cron, sql-update, sql-order-by

I have a table `posts`

```
 id_post   |  status
  3434        0
  5655        3
  5935        5
  9867        1 
  9990        3 
  10975       5
  11234       3
```

Im running a job cron to update every four hours the posts with status `3` but one by one only.

So,

the first time, update the post `5655` status from 3 to 1

the second time, update the post `9990` status from 3 to 1

the third time, update the post `11234` status from 3 to 1

Im thinking using, but Im not sure of it, because I canno test it locally. (the cron jobs was tested with another sql script in the server and works good)

Im thinking using, but im not sure

```
UPDATE posts
SET    status=1
WHERE  status = 3
ORDER BY id_post ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I just need some confirmation that this sql statement is going to work good one I run it in the cron job on the server. thak you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your query will work as intended in MySQL. Unlike other databases, MySQL supports `order by` and `limit` in `update` statements. Their behavior is [described in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

> The `WHERE` clause, if given, specifies the conditions that identify which rows to update. With no `WHERE` clause, all rows are updated. If the `ORDER BY` clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified. The `LIMIT` clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.

So your query, as it is, would pick the "first" row with `status = 3` (as defined by ordering column `id`), and change the `status` to `1`. The next time it executes, the "next" row with `status = 3` is picked and updated.

Beware, however, that if the content of the table is modified in between consequent executions of the queries (that is, if a row with an earlier `id` is inserted - or changed - with `status = 1`), you might not get the exact behavior that you expect.